If the inner product of two vectors are positive, can one of them be writen as the product of a SPD matrix and other?
Let $a, b\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be two vectors whose inner product is positive, i.e., $\langle a, b\rangle > 0$. Can we find a symmetric positive definite (SPD) matrix $H\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $a = Hb$?

Thanks for @user1551 's comment. We know that the matrix mentioned above always exists. On top of that, if we further have $\langle a, b\rangle > c\|b\|^2$ for some positive $c$, can we construct a matrix $H$ with all its eigenvalues greater than some given constant $L$?

If $\langle a,b\rangle=a^Tb$, you may simply take $H=\frac{aa^T}{a^Tb}+\left(I-\frac{bb^T}{b^Tb}\right)$.

A clever construction! @user1551
